# Updating template with session variable and subscription/publication only updates with previous query and appends information

Tags: javascript, meteor

### How it works

I have a *subscript/publication* set up for a Videos Collection (pretty much a list of video information) and a Specs Collection (a list of information directly related to the Video Collection).

To put it in simple word, A Video belongs to one Spec (aka: specialization) and a Spec can have multiple videos.

So I have a select with a list of Specs. On `change` I would like to load all the Videos in the collection that corresponds to that Spec.

My technique is to simply call `Meteor.subscribe("videos-pub-sub", $(evt.target).val());` when an on change is detected. Once the collection gets updated with the correct information, I use a Session variable to update my template.

Then server side for the publication:

```
    Meteor.publish("videos-pub-sub", function (spec){
        console.log("Publishing videos...");
        var res = [];
        if(spec && spec > 0){
            console.log("Spec not empty: " + spec)
            res = Videos.find({spec: parseInt(spec)});
        }else{
            console.log("Spec not set...")
        }
        console.log("publication " + res.fetch().length);
        return res;
    });
```

### Description of the problem and questions

1. When I select an option my table with the video information does not get added, even though in my console.log the information was retrieved correctly. *However*, the moment I make a second selection the table fills up with the **previous** query. Why?
2. When I make a third select change, the previous query data gets appended to the table. Shouldn't it be replaced? Or do I have to manually empty the table out?

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<select id="categories">
  <option></option>
  {{#each specs}}
  <option value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>


<table id="video_table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Authors</th>
      <th>Date Published</th>
      <th>Abstract</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Private</th>
      <th>Online</th>
      <th>Upload</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="video_tbody">
    {{#each videos}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{id}}</td>
      <td>{{title}}</td>
      <td>{{authors}}</td>
      <td>{{date_published}}</td>
      <td>{{description}}</td>
      <td class="category" data-id="{{spec}}">
        {{specName}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" aria-label="..." checked="{{#if private}}checked{{/if}}">
      </td>
      <td>{{#if online}}<span class="label label-success">Online</span>{{else}}<span class="label label-default">Offline</span>{{/if}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
      </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Relevant JS:**

```
  Template.List.events({
    'change #categories':function(evt){

      Meteor.subscribe("videos-pub-sub", $(evt.target).val());

      console.log('Change #categories detected');
      var vids = Videos.find({}).fetch();
      console.log(vids);

      Session.set("videos-session", Videos.find({}).fetch());
      console.log(Session.get("videos-session"));

    }
  });
```

*If more JS is needed I can provide more.*

I am relatively new to Meteor and I'm still trying to see how things work. If you see anything I can improve on, let me know.

Comment: Part of the issue is that you're subscribing in an event handler, and so possibly creating a new subscription (instead of replacing an old one) each time it is run.   Move your subscription to Template.onCreated with a template.subscribe call.  As an argument pass it a ReacriveVar that gets set in the event handler.  Wrap the subscription in template.autorum so that it reruns any time the ReactiveVar is changed

Comment: @bluebird thanks for the advice. I'll try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw in my projects that, when subscribing/calling something on meteor, sometimes it run next code lines without having received previews server answer, and it bring some problems like yours. So, I usually nest what should be done inside the subscribe/call function, then it is run only after data is returned.

I would do something like this:

```
Template.List.events({
    'change #categories':function(evt){

         Meteor.subscribe("videos-pub-sub", $(evt.target).val(), function(){
               //to empty the table
               $('#video_table').find('tbody').empty();
               var vids = Videos.find({}).fetch();
               Session.set("videos-session", Videos.find({}).fetch());
         });

     }
});
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: That is actually a pretty good idea. I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Worked like magic. Thank you. However, the videos still get appended. Do I have to manually empty out the table? EDIT: I just went ahead and emptied it out manually.